# Problems Not Yet Challenged

Tags: discussion

Sometimes when I get the urge to post a new challenge, I have trouble finding a notable* problem that has not yet been solved upon which to base my challenge (I'm not very creative). I thought it might be cool if we could generate a list of such problems here.

Here are some examples that I tried to find using the search box on Code Golf.

- [Clustering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis)
- [Flow Control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flow_control_%28data%29)
- [Maximum Flow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_flow_problem)

Here is one example of a problem that *has* been used before (many times).

- [Shortest Path](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem)

  - Already used [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/17455/18487), [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2645/18487), and [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/153/18487).

Please post notable* problems that have not yet been touched. Post as many as you can think of. Correct other answers (and this question) if you see one that *has* been used before, but make sure that you provide a link.

If you decide to use one of the problems, leave a comment saying that you took it and link to the challenge.

<sub>*A notable problem is one that has been discussed in Academia as opposed to one you just thought of.</sub>

Comment: I would be surprised if max flow isn't covered by one of the various calculate-the-resistance questions.

Comment: Am I right that we have hardly covered any data structures on PPCG?

Comment: I find it amusing that Peter is the only answerer yet.

Answer (score 11):

#### Graph theory

The basics have been done (sometimes more than once), but some advanced stuff is still up for grabs:

- Fractional graph-theoretic properties (e.g. fractional chromatic number)
- [fastest-code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastest-code) vertex-connectivity.
- ...

Ones which have been done already:

- Shortest path / reachability (too many to mention)
- Connected components: [3x3 Connected Components](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/42595/194), [Are you in the biggest room?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/32015/194), and others
- Eulerian path: [Burning Bridges](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/128425/194)
- [Longest path](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem): [Building a long chain of words](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/44922/194) (and with constraints: [Racketeer Taxi Driver](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/32762/194))
- Diameter: [Find the diameter of a word graph](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/187132/194)
- Travelling salesman: [Alex the Truck Driver](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/11310/194), [Travelling Salesman](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/31898/194), [Hamilton is coming to town](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/67611/194)
- Colouring: [Four color theorem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/40339/194), [Find the Chromatic Number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/37709/194), [Graph 5-Coloring](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/170671/194)
- Edge elimination: [Edge Elimination Number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/40292/194)
- Cycle detection: [Infinite Labyrinths](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/48284/194)
- Counting cycles in graph with out-degree 1: [Count the terminal cycles of a directed graph](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/26578/194)
- Longest cycle: [Longest Cycle in a Graph](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/107274/194)
- Topological sort: [City names game](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/6641/194)
- Clustering coefficient: [Calculate Network Average Clustering Coefficient](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/6485/194)
- Max flow: [BWInf 2011, question 5: Twin towns](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/4168/194)
- Min cost flow: [Minimum-cost flow problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/179382/194)
- Planarity testing: [Is My Graph Planar?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/51564/194)
- Bipartite testing: [Is it bipartite?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/148370/194)
- Bipartite matching: [Take one to make one](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/147194/194)
- Maximum matching: [Find maximal matching in divisibility relation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/64745/194)
- Independent set: [Find the largest independent set in a high-dimensional lattice-like graph](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/54354/194) (asks a special case; I think a question asking for IS for general graphs would not be a dupe of this, but would be of maximum clique)
- Maximum clique: [Do the NP: find the largest clique](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/141053/71420)

Comment: Edge colouring? Finding the dual graph? To avoid duplicates and suggestions that *have* been done, it might be useful to include some of said basics with strike-through markup and a link to the question.

Answer (score 9):

### Combinatorics

The number of ways to quarter a chessboard: http://oeis.org/A003213 . Requires some work to explain what exactly it means to quarter a chessboard.

There's one question about knot theory, but it's about testing whether a given knot is the unknot. How many prime alternating tangle types of knot are there with `n` crossings? http://oeis.org/A047051 . An alternative approach to this one would be to generalise it: A047051 has an ordinary generating function `A(z)` which satisfies a quintic equation `p_5(z) A(z)^5 + ... + p_1(z) A(z) + p_0(z) = 0` where each of the `p_i` is a polynomial in `z` with integer coefficients. How about a question to evaluate ogfs defined by similar polynomial relationships and a suitable number of initial terms?

For further combinatoric ideas, watch the [OEIS webcam](http://oeis.org/webcam) until you spot something interesting.

Comment: Perfect! We need more like this one. It's so easy to post them, and someone else can turn it into a nice pretty challenge with well-defined inputs and outputs and such.

Answer (score 3):

I stumbled upon some course notes for a course on multi-agent modelling which has a list of [ideas for things to model](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/courses/mam2005/Ideas_for_models.htm). Not all of them would be suitable, and I think one or two have been done, but it can serve as a source of ideas.

I actually found it while doing a bit of background reading on Paterson's worms, because [this question on math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/909961/5676) seemed like a promising idea for a challenge. (My suggestion would be a [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) which takes worm definition and number of steps and outputs an svg).

Answer (score 2):

## Puzzles and Games

Single-player puzzles/games can easily be formulated as either [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) (solve it) or [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge) (try to optimize the score). Two-player games can be formulated as [king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill). Indeed there are many more puzzles than you think.

- [List of NP-complete problems: Games and puzzles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_NP-complete_problems#Games_and_puzzles)
- [List of PSPACE-complete problems: Games and puzzles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_PSPACE-complete_problems#Games_and_puzzles)
- [List of Nikoli puzzles on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nikoli_(publisher)#Nikoli_puzzles)
- [Logic Puzzles category on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Logic_puzzles)
- **[List of puzzles supported by Cross+A, the puzzle solver & generator](http://www.cross-plus-a.com/puzzles.htm)**